# Прописать в файл .htaccess, чтобы все URL обрабатывались скриптом index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое правило необходимо прописать в файл .htaccess, чтобы все URL обрабатывались скриптом index.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

если адрес будет подобным site.ru/category/toys, то в скрипте **category/toys** можно словить через $_GET['q']

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь